# How to improve filtering in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have next `ng-model`:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" iplaceholder="Add New Filter"></input>
```

And this is how I'm displaying data:

```
<ul>
  <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in availableFilters | filter:query">
    <a ng-click="addFilter(item)">{{item | toUserListHeader}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I have this `availableFilrtes` object that I use as data holder:

```
["black car","white car", "red car", "blue car"]
```

And If I'm entering for example **bl** - black car & blue car will be displayed, but if I dont remember exact order in which words are written, and I also don't remember the full name of the word.

So If now I enter next field in the input:

`car black`

I won't get any results, but I would like to get `black car` as a result.

How can I improve the search?

Comment: you could do that by creating you custom filter..in that split the word you enter..and then check each word is present or not..if it present then return those result

Comment: Alternatively you can use .$ like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) if you need Any Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution to your problem would be to create a custom filter for your application that does a deep match of your search terms against the values.

I've put together the following plunker showing how you could do this [http://plnkr.co/edit/Nt...](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZxFYw3WJuTvcyfCYbNoI?p=preview).

The basic gist is to create a custom filter with some logic which could be similar to the following;

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .filter('filterCar', function() {
    return function(items, term) {
      if (term !== undefined) {
        var newTerm = term.split(' ');
        return items.filter(function(item) {
          // Check against new term whether it's a match.
          var matches = 0;
          var newItem = item.split(' ');
          for (var i = 0; i < newTerm.length; i++) {
            //iterate over search term and check that all matches
            for (var m = 0; m < newItem.length; m++) {
              if (newItem[m].indexOf(newTerm[i]) !== -1) matches++;
            }
          }
          return matches >= newTerm.length;
        });
      } else {
        return items;
      }
    }
  });
```

**UPDATE::**

Important to note this line

```
return matches >= newTerm.length;
```

Checking simply if they are equal in another given answer will not give you the desired behaviour as entering just `c` will give two matches against one search term with regards to "Black car".

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Can you please explain what ```term``` is doing here? It's not very clear for me.

Comment: Term is the search term you type into the field such as "car black"

Comment: I don't really get what this line does: ```return matches >= newTerm.length;``` especially the ```>=```. Can you please explain?

Comment: The code uses `Array.filter`. We are filtering the items array to only leave items that match the search term. The search term is also split into an array of words that are each compared to items. If matches is greater than or equal to the length of the search term, it means that the current item in the for loop is a match. For example if you had "red car" and the search term was "c", you would get 1 match as "c" appears in "car". "C" is just one word so the search term length is 1. 1 is equal to 1 so "red car" is a match when searching "c". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split out your input array by `" "` spaces so that you could verify that each input is present there in any of the element of `ng-repeat` array. Filter will handle the that all the variable of inputs are matched or not. If they gets matched then only return the element of an array.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
  <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in availableFilters | myFilter: query">
    <a ng-click="addFilter(item)">{{item | toUserListHeader}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    //will do return splited arrray by space
    function splitArray(val) {
        if(angular.isArray())
            return val.trim().split(' ');
        return [];
    };

    return function(array, input) {
        //slitting search input by space " "
        var toSearch = splitArray(input);
        if(input){
           return array;
        }
        return array.filter(function (value) {
            //splitting ng-repeat array value by  " "
            var singleValue = splitArray(value), count = 0;
            //looping over it to check that exists in search element
            for (var i = 0; i < singleValue.length; i++) {
                //gets match then increment count.
                if (toSearch.indexOf(singleValue[i]) !== -1)
                    ++count;
            }
            //return all value if all search elements matched
            return toSearch.length == count;
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: should I apply it as a usual filter?

Comment: @Tachi yupe you could use..look at the updated answer

Comment: The code in this answer didn't work for me http://plnkr.co/edit/BJikxAh8y6tx0xldv7ho?p=preview.

Comment: @jh3y I gave an idea..I didn't manage state the code..sorry for that.. i'll get it working once I've access to my machine

Comment: @PankajParkar no worries, not trying to pick a fight :D It just wasn't made clear that it wasn't working code in the answer and asker accepted it as working code I think.

Comment: @jh3y I know..That's cool really awesome..sorry I didn't manage to make it working via plunkr :)

Comment: @PankajParkar It's not downovoted. I just removed the upvote when I assigned another answer as a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom filter , if you find car word in the search text remove that.
You can make such different combinations

Comment: You should consider including an example or sample code.  That makes your answer a bit more easy to use.